# multiplying numpy arrays of different size

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, array-broadcasting

Let's say I have:

```
x = numpy.array([1,2,3])
y = numpy.array([1,2])
```

What I want is a vectorized and efficient way of doing:

```
numpy.cos(x)*numpy.cos(y[0])
numpy.cos(x)*numpy.cos(y[1])
```

It's very important this runs as quickly as possible.

Comment: And what is the output supposed to look like?  2 arrays the same size as `x`,  One array `(3,2)`, or `(2,3)` shape?  Or something else?

Comment: I am not sure if I understood your problem, but I think you are just looking for something like this:   `numpy.transpose(numpy.matrix(numpy.cos(y)))*numpy.cos(x)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With these inputs (`x` and `y`) you can tell numpy to add a new axis to your output and then you will be able to obtain a matrix of results, where each pair `x, y` is evaluated:

```
numpy.cos(x[:, numpy.newaxis])*numpy.cos(y)
```

giving in this case:

```
#        y[0]        y[1]
array([[ 0.29192658, -0.2248451 ],   # x[0]
       [-0.2248451 ,  0.17317819],   # x[1]
       [-0.53489523,  0.41198225]])  # x[2]
```